# Connect to QNX on VirtualBox via IP

Tags: windows-7, ide, virtualbox, qnx-neutrino

I would like to connect to QNX Neutrino OS (qconn) running on the VirtualBox from the Momentics IDE running on the Windows 7 (the same computer) via IP on 8000 port. I tried to get IP address of this virtual machine, and it seems to be the same as my real machine's and it doesn't work on it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just to clarify:

- You are using Windows 7 as your host OS
- QNX Neutrino RTOS is running in a VM
- Using Momentics on the Windows host, you want to connect in the IDE to the QNX target
- Let's assume the IP address of your Windows 7 machine is 192.168.1.101 (acquired by going Start ==> Run... ==> cmd ==> ipconfig )

First, have the network type for your QNX OS VM set to NAT (Network Address Translation). Then, you need to setup port forwarding (please see this URL: http://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2010/12/virtualbox-4-nat-port-forwarding-gui/).

Once you've finished, you should be able to connect from the Momentics IDE in Windows 7 to the QNX VM by specifying the following QCONN target in Momentics:

Target: 127.0.0.1:8000
HOSTNAME: QNX_NTO

The forwarding you setup will cause all connections to 127.0.0.1:8000 (the Windows host loopback connection) on port 8000 to be automatically redirected to your QNX VM.

I've done this myself and it worked. Hope this helps for you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, configure your QNX guest virtual machine to use `Host-Only Networking` - this will put it on a private network segment with your host Windows 7. You should then be able to access it by the IP address is it assigned. By default your Win7 host will have an address of 192.168.56.1 and your virtual machine will likely be assigned 192.168.56.2.

If your guest requires access to the internet or other networks, you could experiment with other network options like `Bridged` (the virtual machine would appear as another computer on your same network) or `NAT` (you would need to add port forwarding options).