# Connect to QNX on VirtualBox with Momentics

Tags: virtualbox, qnx-neutrino, momentics

I install QNX Neutrino OS on VirtualBox and Momentics on Win.

My Win10 PC IP is 192.168.1.4 and QNX IP is 10.0.2.15

In VB i forward port:

- TCP
- Host-adress 192.168.1.4
- Host-port 8000
- Guest-adress 10.0.2.15
- Guest-port 8000

I type "qconn" and did next -- [first](https://tunecomp.net/allow-incoming-ping-echo-request-without-disabling-windows-10-firewall/) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725642/connect-to-qnx-on-virtualbox-via-ip).
But command "ping 10.0.2.15" from cmd return "Request timed out."

And QNX Target in Momentics return "Not connected" to each my attempts.

Thank you in advance for your help.

P.S.-- Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change VirtualBox to VMWare with same .iso and it just work.